# Bazel query for specific type of source files

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to use `bazel query` to return the contents of a particular attribute inside of a rule? I'd like to be able to print out a list of exported headers (the `hdrs` attribute of a `cc_library`) with full (workspace-relative) paths.

The full story is I'd like to execute a `bazel build` and then use an external script to package artifacts for another build system to use, so I need to be able to grab the headers and compiled libraries.

For the headers, I figure I'll query for the `cc_library` targets that are marked as publicly visible, get the transitive closure of their dependencies, and then take the union of their `hdrs` attributes as the header files I need to copy.

I can get the dependency list using:

```
bazel query 'kind("cc_library", 
                  deps(attr("visibility",
                            "//visibility:public",
                            //... except //tools/...)
                      )
                 )'
```

I can get a full source file list by nesting the above:

```
bazel query 'kind("source file", 
                  deps(kind("cc_library", 
                            deps(attr("visibility",
                                      "//visibility:public",
                                      //... except //tools/...)
                                )
                      ))
                  )' --noimplicit_deps
```

However, it's not clear from the source list which headers are "exported" in the `hdrs` attribute vs. unexported via the `srcs` attribute. Is there a bazel query function that can pick out the contents of specific attributes of BUILD rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [labels function](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#labels).